# chef-server-ctl reconfigure giving error

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to install chef-server on my VM.
While doing chef-server-ctl reconfigure I am getting the following error. Can someone help me in resolving this error.
thanks.

```
* user[opscode] action create

================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'user[opscode]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '4'
---- Begin output of ["useradd", "-s", "/bin/sh", "-d", "/opt/opscode/embedded", "-r", "opscode"] ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: useradd: Can't get unique system UID (no more available UIDs)
useradd: can't create user
---- End output of ["useradd", "-s", "/bin/sh", "-d", "/opt/opscode/embedded", "-r", "opscode"] ----
Ran ["useradd", "-s", "/bin/sh", "-d", "/opt/opscode/embedded", "-r", "opscode"] returned 4
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear: "useradd: Can't get unique system UID (no more available UIDs)". The usual reason is the number of users created exceed the available uids between `SYS_UID_MIN` and `SYS_UID_MAX` defined in `/etc/login.defs`

Comment: @Tensibai I have edited the /etc/login.defs and increased SYS_UID_MAX value. But still I am getting the same error.

Comment: sry, it's working fine now